# Correctly aligning labels for subgroups within a tiledlayout

Tags: matlab, layout, label, alignment, subplot

I want to put 5 plots in a figure using tiledlayout, 2x2 plots at the top then a plot at the bottom that spans two columns. There should be two sets of axis labels: one for the 2x2 plot and another for the bottom plot. My MWE is

```
x = linspace(-2,2,100);
y1 = sin(x);
y2 = cos(x);
y3 = sin(x).*cos(2*x);
y4 = sin(2*x).*cos(x);
y5 = y3 + y4;

figure('PaperUnits', 'inches', 'PaperSize', [4 6], 'PaperPosition', [0 0 4 6]);
t = tiledlayout(3,2,'TileSpacing','compact','Padding','compact');

nexttile; plot(x,y1); title('y_1');
nexttile; plot(x,y2); title('y_2');
nexttile; plot(x,y3); title('y_3');
nexttile; plot(x,y4); title('y_4');

xlabel(t,'time t_\alpha')
ylabel(t,'amplitude \alpha')

nexttile([1 2]); plot(x,y5); title('y_5');

xlabel('time t_\beta')
ylabel('amplitude \beta')

saveas(gcf,'myfig.jpg')
```

This gives me the following figure:

[image]

I want the `amplitude \alpha` ylabel and the `time t_alpha` xlabel to be aligned correctly for the 2x2 plots (as indicated by my red annotations). Is there a way to do this?

I'm using MATLAB R2020a. Note that the `tiledlayout` function was introduced in R2019b.

Comment: Perhaps you can have a a nested tiled layout, where the outer layout is 3x1, its first two positions are taken by a 2x2 tiled layout and the last position is a simple plot. I never tried this myself, but I think it could work. Please also mention the MATLAB version you're using.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An approximation of what you wanted can be achieved by the approach I mentioned in my comment (using a "nested" `tiledlayout`). The steps necessary to make it work are:

1. Creating an external vertical layout.
2. Reserving the first two rows for the nested `tiledlayout`, by asking a 2-by-1 `nexttile`, making the resulting axes hidden, and creating a [`uipanel`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/uipanel.html) in its place. Calling `uipanel` is necessary because the [`parent` of a `tiledlayout`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/tiledlayout.html#mw_e3cd9ee5-1fb0-45b1-943f-16028a8ee66d) cannot be another `tiledlayout`, but it *can* be a `Panel`.
3. Plotting everything in the appropriate panels, and applying the labels accordingly.

```matlab
x = linspace(-2,2,100);
y1 = sin(x);
y2 = cos(x);
y3 = sin(x).*cos(2*x);
y4 = sin(2*x).*cos(x);
y5 = y3 + y4;

hF = figure('PaperUnits', 'inches', 'PaperSize', [4 6], 'PaperPosition', [0 0 4 6]);
tOut = tiledlayout(hF,3,1);
hAx = nexttile(tOut, [2,1]); hAx.Visible = 'off';
hP = uipanel(hF, 'Position', hAx.OuterPosition, 'BorderWidth', 0);
tIn = tiledlayout(hP,2,2,'TileSpacing','compact','Padding','compact');

nexttile(tIn); plot(x,y1); title('y_1');
nexttile(tIn); plot(x,y2); title('y_2');
nexttile(tIn); plot(x,y3); title('y_3');
nexttile(tIn); plot(x,y4); title('y_4');

xlabel(tIn,'time t_\alpha')
ylabel(tIn,'amplitude \alpha')

hAx = nexttile(tOut); plot(x,y5); title('y_5');

xlabel(hAx, 'time t_\beta')
ylabel(hAx, 'amplitude \beta')
```

Resulting in:

[image]

---

From here you can try tweaking the individual GUI elements (layouts, axes, panel) to get a result closer to what you wanted.

A completely different route I can suggest is starting with your code and adding the labels for the top 4 plots using the [`annotation`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/annotation.html) function (instead of `xlabel` and `ylabel`).

Comment: thanks for the detailed solution. I noticed that when the figure is exported to jpg or pdf using `saveas`, the 2x2 plots always have a gray background while the bottom plot doesn't. Why does this happen?

Comment: This is likely because of the panel's background color. See [solution](https://undocumentedmatlab.com/articles/transparent-uipanels#HG2) at the bottom of the post (the code that uses `JavaFrame`). You should run that code before exporting the figure.